# How to create a batch script that will only copy files with specific parts of the file name

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch script that will only copy files with a  certain part of the file name

Example I need to copy a file with * _*_2006  in its name

12345_12_2006_12345678.dcm

But I do not want to copy any files like the below examples

12345_13_2007_123452006.dcm

or

21355_10_2008_200654321.dcm

*_ * _2006*.dcm   will not work

You will notice that in the two examples that I do not want to copy 2006 is also there but in a different location in the file name.

Answer (score 2):

```
*_ *_2006_*.dcm
```

should work so it should

Edit: or to be more restrictive:

```
?????_??_2006_*.dcm
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
*_2006_*.dcm
```